# How to refresh or redirect browser to specified URL in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

There is similar function in PHP:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit();
```

How to properly redirect browser to new page or refresh current one?

---

I am using Google App Engine Framework.

Comment: That's largely impossible to answer without knowing what Python framework (or CGI script) you're running on the server.  You'll have to post some code so we know what you're talking about.

Comment: More details? Are you writing a plain CGI, are yuo using Django/web.py/... What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/redirects.html) explains how to use redirects in the Google App Engine Framework, using the **redirect** method of the webapp.RequestHandler. The most relevant code is:

```
class FormHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        if processFormData(self.request):
            self.redirect("/home")
        else:
            # Display the form, possibly with error messages.
```

You should read the whole page to see how it fits into your app.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a body, too. E.g. an empty one, just to send the newline separator.